# Individual connections VS shared DB connection in a multi-thread app?

Tags: database, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm currently supporting a multi-thread app (Delphi 10.4) that generates about 20 threads to take data from remote punch-clocks and enter it into a DB table (same one for all threads), but does so by having each thread generate its own (MSADO) connection on construction. Now while this does make the application thread-safe since they don't share a resource, would it be a better idea efficiency-wise to make one connection that the threads would share and ensure thread-safety by using TMonitor, critical sections or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how much writes you have to the database. If you use the single connection and still use one insert statement for each thread, then you are not solving anything. In addition, your application will slow down due to the synchronization between the threads waiting their turn on the database connection.

To do this in a proper way, you will need to apply something like a `producer` - `consumer` pattern with a queue between the producer(s) (the threads fetching data from the punch-clock) and the consumer (the db writer thread).

Once the reader thread fetches the data, it will:

1. lock the queue access
2. add it to the queue.
3. unlock the queue

Once the writer thread starts running, it will:

1. lock the queue access
2. gather all the data from the queue,
3. remove messages from the queue
4. unlock the queue
5. prepare singe `INSERT` statement for all rows from the queue
6. execute the transaction on the DB
7. sleep for a short period of time (allow other threads to work)

This is not data safe approach, since if there is failure between the data removed from the queue and data committed to the database, the data will be lost.

As you see, this is more complex approach, so if you don't experiance DB congestion, it's not worth to use single connection.

> Note: There is also approach to use a pool of DB connections which is the most used pattern in this cases. With the DB pool, a smaller number of connections are shared among large number of threads trying to read/write the database.